# Sorting array and displaying button state

Tags: angular, typescript

I've implemented sorting on my RSS feed reader app in Angular2, however my solution in far from elegant and scalable. In HTML, button has 3 states: sorted ASC(1), sorted DESC(-1) and inactive(0). That helps me to manage glyphicons on the buttons, but it is a lot of variable tracking, value changing and checking. I need some help to improve this solution.
Here is my code in app.component:

```js
  abcSort = 0; // 0 = not sorted, 1 = sorted ascending, -1 = sorted descending
  dateSort = 0; // 0 = not sorted, 1 = sorted ascending, -1 = sorted descending

  onSortAbc() {
    if (this.abcSort === 0 || this.abcSort === -1) {
      this.feedService.sortByAbcAsc(this.feeds);
      this.abcSort = 1;
    } else {
      this.feedService.sortByAbcDesc(this.feeds);
      this.abcSort = -1;
    }
    this.dateSort = 0;
  }

  onSortDate() {
    if (this.dateSort === 0 || this.dateSort === -1) {
      this.feedService.sortByDateAsc(this.feeds);
      this.dateSort = 1;
    } else {
      this.feedService.sortByDateDesc(this.feeds);
      this.dateSort = -1;
    }
    this.abcSort = 0;

  }

  private resort() {
    if (this.dateSort === 1) {
      this.feedService.sortByDateAsc(this.feeds);
    } else if (this.dateSort === -1) {
      this.feedService.sortByDateDesc(this.feeds);
    } else if (this.abcSort === 1) {
      this.feedService.sortByAbcAsc(this.feeds);
    } else if (this.abcSort === -1) {
      this.feedService.sortByAbcDesc(this.feeds);
    }
  }
```

resort() is used to sort RSS feed the way it was sorted last after I refresh the feed (e.g. add new feed).

app.component.html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button [ngClass]="{'glyphicon': true, 'glyphicon-arrow-up': abcSort ==1,'glyphicon-arrow-down': abcSort ==-1 , 'active' : abcSort !=0 }"
    class="btn btn-default" (click)="onSortAbc()" btnRadio="Left">Abc</button>
  <button [ngClass]="{'glyphicon': true, 'glyphicon-arrow-up': dateSort == 1,'glyphicon-arrow-down': dateSort ==-1, 'active' : dateSort !=0 }"
    class="btn btn-default" (click)="onSortDate()" btnRadio="Right">Date</button>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: First thing I'd probably do is move the logic out of the markup. Instead of those ternary conditionals and so forth in the button markup to determine class, I'd probably just bind [ngClass]="determineButtonClass()" or some such, and let the component controller (or whatever we call them now) do the decisioning. That'll clean up your markup, which is a step towards elegance. If I think up of anything for the code itself I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, that will make it much prettier.